# LDAP - What to use instead of DirSyncRequestControl

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

I'm migrating some code away from Active Directory re-writing all directory requests to reference classes in System.Directory.Protocols and be LDAP v3 compliant. This is supposed to be a low level v3 LDAP namespace so assumed it wouldn't be polluted with AD specific types. The following code is from a monitor background worker that was already using the System.Directory.Protocols namespace. It opens an async long running request to AD and listens for changes using the Control `DirSyncRequestControl`.

```
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(
        mDNSearchRoot,
        mLdapFilter,
        SearchScope.Subtree,
        mAttrsToWatch
    );
request.Controls.Add(
        new DirSyncRequestControl(
            mCookie,
            mDirSyncOptions
        )
    );

mConn.BeginSendRequest(
        request,
        mRequestTimeout,
        PartialResultProcessing.NoPartialResultSupport,
        endPollDirectory,
        null
    );
```

It sends a cookie as a byte[] that tells the directory when to start querying from which is handy in case the background worker crashes and needs a restart later. In the `endPollDirectory` callback an update cookie is received and persisted immediately to the filesystem in the event of a restart being needed we always know when we last received results from. That cookie is loaded on restart and passed back with the `DirSyncRequestControl`.

The issue I'm facing is that `DirSyncRequestControl` is operating against an OID which specifically is an Active Directory extension, not standard LDAP. Our corporate directory is on IBM based LDAP and can't have AD OIDs and Controls applied. Standard LDAP supports "Persistent Search" 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.3 but .NET doesn't provide a Control that could be added as in the above code. There's also no way to pass arguments like a cookie. The idea with the Persistent Search control is that you open the connection and as time passes the LDAP server sends changes back which I could response to. But on initiating the connection there's no way to specify when to returns results from, only results since the request was started will be received. If the monitor were to die and a directory change happened before the monitor could restart those changes could be neve be handled.

Does anyone know if there's an existing Control compliant with standard LDAP that could be added to the request which operates the way the AD specific `DirSyncRequestControl` does where a start date time could be passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know if there's an existing Control compliant with standard LDAP that could be added to the request which operates the way the AD specific DirSyncRequestControl does where a start date time could be passed?

Standard would be the `1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.1` "Sync Request" control from [RFC 4533](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4533), which is the basis of "[Syncrepl](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin26/replication.html#LDAP%20Sync%20Replication)" directory replication in OpenLDAP and 389-ds.

(Though "standard" does not guarantee that IBM's LDAP server will support it – or that it's enabled on your server specifically, similar to how OpenLDAP requires loading the "syncprov" overlay first.)

```
2.2.  Sync Request Control

   The Sync Request Control is an LDAP Control [RFC4511] where the
   controlType is the object identifier 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.1 and the
   controlValue, an OCTET STRING, contains a BER-encoded
   syncRequestValue.  The criticality field is either TRUE or FALSE.

      syncRequestValue ::= SEQUENCE {
          mode ENUMERATED {
              -- 0 unused
              refreshOnly       (1),
              -- 2 reserved
              refreshAndPersist (3)
          },
          cookie     syncCookie OPTIONAL,
          reloadHint BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
      }

   The Sync Request Control is only applicable to the SearchRequest
   Message.
```

Although dotnet doesn't support this control natively (it seems to focus on just supporting Active Directory extensions), it should be possible to create a custom class [similar to the Dir­Sync­Request­Control class](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/66e64e5feb08ded3247a47ea1dedd1692043cdc2/src/libraries/System.DirectoryServices.Protocols/src/System/DirectoryServices/Protocols/common/DirectoryControl.cs#L447-L512) with the correct OID and correct BER serialization (and somehow handle the "Sync Done" control that delivers the final sync cookie to you, etc).

OpenLDAP's ldapsearch supports calling this control via `ldapsearch -E sync=rp[/cookie]`. On the server side, slapd supports this control for databases that have the "[syncprov](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin26/replication.html#LDAP%20Sync%20Replication)" overlay loaded (which is required for replication).

389-ds (Red Hat Directory Server) supports this control if the [plug-in](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_directory_server/11/html/administration_guide/setting_up_content_synchronization_using_the_syncrepl_protocol) is enabled.

---

The other approach is to have a persistent search for `(modifyTimestamp>=...)` and keep track of the last received entry change timestamp in place of the "cookie". This isn't very accurate, unfortunately.

Comment: The solution is perfect in general, but it seems "IBM® Security Directory Base Server v6.4" which we're running doesn't support that control :(

Comment: We've ended up going with changelog entries being enabled on the LDAP server. CN=changelog now stored details of entries that have been changed. I keep track of the last changenumber that was queried, then on each poll interval increment in a loop querying until the response Entries.Count == 0, then individually query all the returned targetdn attributes. The simplicity of a Control would have been nice, but without knowledge of how to extend an ldap backend plus time constraints, then changelog approach works well.